# Pinescript v5 creating multiple boxes in wick zones... 1 box is working, just cant get multiple

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, indicator, candlestick-chart

I am working on an indicator that draws boxes in a HTF using the Up candle Top Wicks and down candle Bottom Wicks.

Right now it will draw an upBox where i want in blue and a downBox in red... but then it will end somewhere it seems randomly, and then a new one will start at the next time the situation occurs

what i need is for it to draw the box everytime, regardless of whether there is an upBox or a downBox there already or not

i really want the upBox to stop drawing when there is a new higherhigh that goes above the upHiLine, etc... but i haven't worked out how to do that yet of course either

Can anybody help?

[image]

```
//@version=5
indicator("Intraday wicks",overlay=true, max_bars_back = 200, max_boxes_count = 200)

//Input
string tfInput = input.timeframe("15", "Timeframe")

// Initialize variables on bar zero only, so they preserve their values across bars.
bool up = close > open
bool down = close < open
var upHi = float(na)
var upCl = float(na)
var upOp = float(na)
var upLo = float(na)
var downLo = float(na)
var downCl = float(na)
var downHi = float(na)
var downOp = float(na)
var line upHiLine = na
var line upLoLine = na
var line downHiLine = na
var line downLoLine = na
var box upBox = na
var box downBox = na

// Detect changes in timeframe.
bool newTF = ta.change(time(tfInput))
if newTF
    if up //if new bar in HTF is Bullish var, reset values and create new lines
        upHi := high //collect the top of the top wick value
        upCl := close //collect the bottom of top wick value
        //up high line is the top wick of a bull candle as a line 
        upHiLine := line.new(bar_index, upHi, bar_index, upHi, color = color.white, width = 1)
        //up lo line is the bottom wick of a bull candle as a line 
        upLoLine := line.new(bar_index, upCl, bar_index, upCl, color = color.white, width = 1)
        //up box is a box drawn beteen the top and bottom wicks of a bull candle
        upBox := box.new(bar_index, upHi, bar_index,upCl, border_color = na, bgcolor = color.rgb(47, 93, 229))
    else
        // On other bars, extend the right coordinate of lines and box.
        line.set_x2(upHiLine, bar_index)
        line.set_x2(upLoLine, bar_index)
        box.set_right(upBox, bar_index)
    int(na)
    
    if down //if new bar in HTF is Bearish var, reset values and create new lines
        downCl := close //collect the top of the top wick value
        downLo := low //collect the bottom of top wick value
        //up high line is the top wick of a bull candle as a line 
        downHiLine := line.new(bar_index, downCl, bar_index, downCl, color = color.white, width = 1)
        //up lo line is the bottom wick of a bull candle as a line 
        downLoLine := line.new(bar_index, downLo, bar_index, downLo, color = color.white, width = 1)
        //up box is a box drawn beteen the top and bottom wicks of a bull candle
        downBox := box.new(bar_index, downCl, bar_index,downLo, border_color = na, bgcolor = color.rgb(234, 70, 125))
    
    else
        // On other bars, extend the right coordinate of lines and box.
        line.set_x2(downHiLine, bar_index)
        line.set_x2(downLoLine, bar_index)
        box.set_right(downBox, bar_index)

    int(na)
```

Answer (score 2):

ok so i found one error in my code.....

```
box.set_right(upBox, bar_index)
```

changed to

```
box.set_extend(id=upBox, extend=extend.right)

[pic of new boxes][1]
```